# Deleting comments from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am making a forum webpage where I'll put delete this buttons under each comment. Now when you press this button, I send the ID of the comment to PHP file using ajax which looks like this:

```
function Deletethis(index) {
var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
    if (result==true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "deletepost.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: index,
        success: function(){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
    } else return false;
}
```

Now the problem is I can't receive it from the PHP end. I've used the debugger and saw that the index value is right. My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "test") or die("DIE");
if (isset($_POST['index'])) {
    $SoonToBeDeletedComment = $_POST['index'];
};
$index = intval($SoonToBeDeletedComment);            
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM commentsbox WHERE commentsbox.`ID` = $index");
echo "Post Deleted...";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My code doesnt give any errors but it doesn't delete the post either. When I do the same process manually on navicat, it is working so I thought maybe the index is a string and it should be an integer. So I used intval but it didnt solve the problem either. Any ideas to help me improve my code is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see if the id is posted?

Comment: Have you tried emailing yourself a var_dump($_POST) just to make sure that PHP is receiving what you expect it to receive?

Comment: @LifeHacker Yes it is

Comment: @Mike Willis how can I do that? Sorry Im still getting used to this

Comment: You don't send any variables to php file. They're should be in `data{}` with correct name

Comment: mail( "yourEmailAddress", "subject", var_dump( $_POST ) );

Comment: @turson i tried it before it doesnt work

Comment: @MikeWillis Are you seriously suggesting emailing as a debug tool? Nothing better?

Comment: @Shomz if its gonna solve it Im not whining :D

Comment: It's not going to solve anything :) You can simply do the var_dump and read what it says, no need to email anybody, post to FB or instagram :D

Comment: @Shomz lol I tried it though and it returned array(0) { } Am I doing it wrong or was I supposed to get that

Comment: @Shomz outputting the var dump results to screen would work fine too. I frequently email these things to myself, I don't post to FB or any other silly things you listed. In either case the result is the same, you see the POST data. Actually he'd have to do a print_r( $_POST, 1 ) to email it to himself now that I think about it.

Comment: @MikeWillis Haha, I know, the silly things were a reaction to how I found emailing the debug results silly. Btw. you can do `var_export` for emailing - it's similar to what you did with the second parameter of `print_r`.

Comment: @Shomz I frequently hide all output on my receiving PHP scripts, even when debugging, so anyone who stumbles onto a page won't see anything. Call it paranoia. So the email thing has become my default "silly" way of finding out what was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery's [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, the `data` property needs to be an object, not a string (string only it it's a full GET query string, actually, but it's not what you need here).

So, try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "deletepost.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {id: index},
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        // location.reload();
    }
});
```

And then in PHP, get it as:

```
$_POST['id']
```

---

UPDATE

Sanity checklist:

- is your `Deletethis` function actually receiving the index?
- is your ajax calling the right script?
- is ajax data property an object, like I explained above?
- what is the output of the PHP script?
- what are the contents of `$_POST`?
- is the id inside the `$_POST` array (`$_POST['id']`)?
- does the row with that id exist in the db?

These questions should help you pinpoint the problem more accurately.

Comment: Hm, why don't you just do `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP, nothing else... And see what's being sent.

Comment: It returned array(0) { }?

Comment: Alright, that's something. JS is not sending any data. Can you verify that the index value in your script is there before you do the ajax call?

Comment: I used the debugger and when i look at the value of index it gives me 4

Comment: It shouldnt send an array actually that might be the problem

Comment: No, no, $_POST is always an array, so in your case $_POST['id'] would be 4. Modify this: `var result = confirm("Want to delete index " + index + "?");` That way you'll see the index in the popup every time.

Comment: I added a little list to my answer... Go over each item and test. (you've already answered a few here in the comments)

Comment: Thank you very much I actually saw what I was doing wrong... It was returning the id = 1, even though I already have deleted it. So I was trying to delete something that was already deleted. I saw that when I checked my database again. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Apparently I am really tired :D

Comment: It happens to everyone, you're welcome. :) Keep that sanity list somewhere, you might need it again :D

Answer (score 0):

You send param to your PHP code without define his name : `data: { index: index } // param : value`

```
function Deletethis(index)
{
    if ( confirm("Want to delete?") )
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "deletepost.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                index: index
            },
            success: function(){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Check also if your PHP code is working by calling page directly with param.

Comment: I tried it before that doesnt work :/ PHP doesnt work when I directly call the page because it says $SoonToBeDeletedComment is undefined

Comment: If you call PHP directly it's because you use $_POST.
Check with $_GET just for the test

Comment: replace this with $_GET : if (isset($_GET['index'])) { $SoonToBeDeletedComment = $_GET['index']; } next call you php file directly with param (and show us url you call)

Comment: still getting the same error Undefined variable: SoonToBeDeletedComment

Comment: What url do you call ? Here is the problem.

Comment: I know its gonna give that error because Im directly calling the php file in the url section. But nonetheless when I call it from the website, it still doesnt work

Comment: Can you explain actually I might be doing something wrong considering that Im really tired